# Add TaxonomyFieldValue to a TaxonomyFieldValueCollection inside my CSOM code

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am creating a TaxonomyFieldValueCollection as follow:-

```
TaxonomyField deptField = clientContext.Web.GetList("/sites/Filing/lists/" + "FilingSystem").Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Fund") as TaxonomyField;
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection tfvc = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(clientContext,null,deptField);
```

but i am not sure how i can add `new TaxonomyFieldValue() { TermGuid = f.Id.ToString(), WssId = -1, Label = f.Name }` to the `tfvc`?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can add values to TaxonomyFieldValueCollection using  [TaxonomyFieldValueCollection.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj166183%28v%3Doffice.15%29#remarks)

> TaxonomyFieldValueCollection tfvc = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(Context, null, targetField);
>
> tfvc.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(@"label|b3705gudic4dc4071");
>
> tfvc.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(@"label2|b705gudicc4565465");
>
> targetField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(targetitems, tfvc);
>
> targetitems.Update();
>   context.ExecuteQuery();

More references:

- https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-update-the-taxonomy-field-single-value-or-multiple-value-using-c-patterns-and-practices-in-sharepoint-office-365/
- https://unnieayilliath.com/2015/08/24/sharepoint-2013-updateclear-taxonomy-field-value-using-c-csom/

BR,
Baker